# Electron js: development differences between windows and mac

Tags: windows, macos, electron, desktop-application, electron-builder

Context:

- I'm starting to implement a cross-platform app for Windows and Mac with electron Js.
- The bundle that will use or use this electron Js app is developed in Angular.

My questions are:

Are there differences when developing the app for windows and mac?
Differences in, for example, how it is handled at the code level:

- Native menus.
- Notifications.
- System app events: Minimize, maximize, close.
- Running the app in background.

If there are differences, should I indicate them at the code level or Electron Js take care of translating this to each system and I just develop generically without worrying about it?

If I have to indicate at the code level, should I have two projects or can I indicate in the same project that and when something is used for Windows and for Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Electron is designed to be cross OS compatible.

There **should** be no difference between building an Electron application for Windows, MacOS or Linux.

Implementing the use of native menus, notifications, system app events (minimize, maximize, close), etc **with Electron's API's** will ensure your application is cross OS compatible.

Some features of Electron modules may be particular to only a certain OS but these are clearly defined and explained within Electron's [Docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/) and [API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app). EG: The `movable` option when creating a new window [new BrowserWindow({movable: true})](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) can only be implemented on MacOS and Window, not Linux.

As Node.js is bundled with Electron, you will need to be mindful on how you implement some Node functions. EG: Directory separators will be different between Operating Systems so using methods such as [`path.join([...paths])`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/path.html#pathjoinpaths) would be prudent to make you code cross OS compatible.

As Chromium is also bundled with Electron, keep in mind your use of any particularly new HTML features. Ensure you are not trying to use cutting edge HTML features which have not made it to the version of Chromium you are using within your version of Electron.

Lastly, Angular is a front end framework, this will not be affected by the type of OS used.

In summary, one code base, designed and coded well, will work without issue on Windows, MacOS or Linux.